# ImageView bounds of image Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to get bounds on screen of image in ImageView. How can I achieve this?
I need left top point and bottom right point of image displayed in ImageView?

**EDIT:** ImageView is full screen view but it consumes all screen, and if I have for example landscape picture shown in portrait mode, black space above and below image will be inside imageView

Comment: 1) get the ImageView's `Matrix` 2) use one of `Matrix#map*` method

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
int b[] = new int [2];
mtimageview.getLocationInWindow(location);
```

Or

```
int b[] = new int [2];
mtimageview.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

And you can change parameter imageview in ***xml*** file:

```
android:scaleType="center"
```